# How do i call activity method from custom view?

Tags: java, android, xml, class, methods

I have a main activity that calls `setContentView()` on a custom view that I created using something like `public myCustomView extends View{}`. My main question is that I have a method inside of the main activity, `functionIWantToCall()` and I want to call it from the `onDraw()` method of the customview because that's where all the action happens. How can I do this?  Alternatively, having a method that repeats itself in the main activity could work too, similar to calling `invalidate()` in the onDraw method.  Can anyone tell me how to go about either of these methods?  I appreciate the help! =)

Comment: Why do you want to call a function of main activity from onDraw(). Instead you can pass the data required in that function to the custom view, add the function in the custom view itself.

Comment: I originally attempted that, however the function I want to call consists of  things like `setContentView()` and calling another function that is also inside the main activity.  For the flow and neatness of the app I'm trying to do it from the main activity

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve with the `View`, but you might also want to look into `Fragment`. It may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static method inside your MainActivity class, which you could then call by doing `MainActivity.functionIWantTocall()`. This will only work so long as you don't have any other function that are object-based inside the method. If you do, you'll get an error that says you can't call non-static methods from a static method.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without any static method inside the MainActivity class?  I tried to do it but there is so many things that are intertwined into the method that I can't make it static without having to rewrite everything I have done so far.

Comment: You can create an instance of the MainActivity and the call the method: `MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();` and then `ma.yourFunction()`, but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. I don't quite understand why you would want a view to rely on your activity so much. I don't think that is a very good design. Views should be independent and should not be relying on an activity. Maybe if you posted your code for the activity and the view, we could help you figure out what your problem really is.